# What is this C programming reading?

Tags: c, file-io

This is the code I am trying to understand:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    unsigned long word;
    ssize_t nr;

    int file = open("koray.txt",O_RDONLY);

    nr = read(file,&word,sizeof(unsigned long));
    printf("%li\n",word);

}
```

`koray.txt` has only 1 character that is `k`.

When I run the program I see:

```
koray@koray-VirtualBox:~$ ./a.out
4195435
```

What is this large value?

Comment: You're never checking the return value of `read`, so why are you having any expectations at all?

Comment: The moral of the story: always initialize your local variables, to have more deterministic programs. The compiler would optimize the initialization if it is unneeded

Comment: @KerrekSB Why shouldn't I have expectations?

Comment: @KorayTugay: Because they are grounded purely in fantasy and not in documented behaviour. You cannot rely on anything but the documented behaviour, everything else is pointless, idle musing. In other words, you are only allowed to expect things that someone promised you.

Comment: @KerrekSB I have no idea what you are talking about :) Thanks anyway..

Comment: @KorayTugay - You are expecting this to not be a large value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be random garbage in the `word` variable because you never initialized it. Then `read` will only be able to get one byte from the file (`nr` probably returned 1, you should check that!) which saves one byte, but the `word` variable still has 3-7 bytes of uninitialized junk in it that gets printed.

Comment: Thanks I see. When I initialize it to 0, I will see 107 printed which is fine I think..

Comment: @KorayTugay - Also it appears your system / processor is little endian (least significant byte first), so the read places the 'k' in the least significant byte of word.

Comment: Yeah, 107 is the ascii 'k' so that's it. The other answer's point about the printf is a good one too btw.

Comment: I tried with text file containing the characters ak and I got the result: 01101011 01100001. That is: k and then a... Why is that?

Comment: Ah, because the little endian thing right.. It reads a first and stores in the last 8 bits, and then reads k and stores in the first 8 bits?

Comment: I tried with the character 'ğ' and I am getting the value:696260, which does not make any sense?

Answer (score 4):

**Problem 1**

You never checked the return of `read()`, so it may very well fail.

Even if it does not fail, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415501/2173917) by Mr. **@Adam D. Ruppe**, if the file contains less element than `sizeof(unsigned long)`, then the remaining part of `word` will hold the garbage value, because `word` is a local variable and having *automatic* storage duration, which contains indeterminate value unless initialized explicitly.

**Point 2**

You used `%li` to print `unsigned long`. UB. you need to use `%lu`.

Comment: `i` is for `signed int`. `u` is for `unsigned int`